# How does one remove numeric id ending for restful URL in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, we track urls such as

```
/app/person/1
/app/person/78
```

or

```
/app/person/pet/456
/app/person/pet/65
```

And we'd like to remove the final Identifier so we can report on the page itself (i.e. `/app/person` and `/app/person/pet`)

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2 ways**:

- **[Search/Replace Filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20search%2Dand%2Dreplace%20filter%3A&text=Click%20the%20Select%20filter%20type,Enter%20the%20Replace%20String.)**: this will overwrite the original URLs with the non-numeric ones (if you ever want to know the exact original URL you're screwed).
- **[Content Grouping](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en)**: this will retain the original URLs, but will create a separate reporting option whereby you can switch from original URLs to your content group (see below example showing the page type, but you can really do whatever you want with content groups, including non-numeric IDs):

  [image]

**In both cases, you'll need a regular expression to handle the conversion:** `([^0-9]+)/[0-9]+` should work (note that with [GA's regular expression engine](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en) you do not need to escape `/`)

Accordingly the content grouping setup would look like:

[image]